# Instagram Widget - Without using third party

Tags: instagram

I want to add instagram widget script on my page. There are lots of site that create widget script to add instagram to your webpage.

But I do not want to use third party tool to created widget script.

Is there any way by which I can directly create widget script from instagram site or developer tool.

Thanks

Comment: Instagram should provide more widgets that don't require a login.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram has a widget that allows you to embed a single image on a web page. More info is here: https://instagram.com/developer/embedding/.

Otherwise you could create your own widget using their api, more info here: https://instagram.com/developer/